# Envoy- QUICHE file not found

Tags: clang, envoyproxy, quic

I am building [Envoy v1.29.1](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/v1.29.1) from source.

I have successfully built the binary on my `ubuntu 22.04` system with `clang 18`, `bazel 6.4.0` and `gcc 11` installed.

When running the test cases, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: /home/test/envoy/source/common/quic/BUILD:573:17: Compiling source/common/quic/send_buffer_monitor.cc failed: (Exit 1): clang failed: error executing command (from target //source/common/quic:send_buffer_monitor_lib) /usr/lib/llvm-18/bin/clang -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fcolor-diagnostics -fno-omit-frame-pointer ... (remaining 148 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
In file included from source/common/quic/send_buffer_monitor.cc:1:
./source/common/quic/send_buffer_monitor.h:3:10: fatal error: 'quiche/quic/core/quic_stream.h' file not found
    3 | #include "quiche/quic/core/quic_stream.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
INFO: Elapsed time: 110.751s, Critical Path: 21.76s
INFO: 3170 processes: 2765 internal, 405 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
//test/common/quic:active_quic_listener_test                    FAILED TO BUILD

Executed 0 out of 1146 tests: 1 fails to build and 1145 were skipped.
```

I ran this command to run the tests-
`bazel test //test/... --config=clang --cxxopt="-Wno-error=thread-safety-reference"  --//bazel:http3=False`